# sed: delete all occurrences of a string except  the first one

Tags: sed

I have a logfile with timestamps in it. Occasionally there are multiple timestamps in one line. Now I would like to remove all of the timestamps from a line but keep the first one.

I can do `s/pattern//2` but that only removes the second occurrence and `sed` doesn't allow something like `s/pattern//2-`.

Any suggestions?

Comment: I should've told that it's the sed of busybox. Sorry for that.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

With GNU `sed`:

```bsh
sed 's/pattern//2g'
```

The `2` specifies that the second pattern and all the rest`g` should remove. So this will keep the first one.

Comment: Which Cygwin has (a port of, apparently) and MacOS does not. Achh! This solution is so much more elegant.

Comment: I couldn't get this to work on macos with builtin sed, and gsed. With builtin sed, it would return `sed: 1: "s/^ *$//2g": more than one number or 'g' in substitute flags` - with gsed, it would be as if nothing happened.

Comment: @balupton that's not available in non-GNU sed; and for the gsed you are expecting substituting _second to last_ empty line (including space characters only lines) **within that line**, which definitely there is no more than one line in a line.

Answer (score 9):

This should work (replace _ by something else should it clash with your logs):

```
sed -e 's/pattern/_&/1' -e 's/\([^_]\)pattern//g' -e 's/_\(pattern\)/\1/'
```

Comment: if you're ever wanting a unique delimiter, use `\n`.

Answer (score 5):

```
sed -e ':begin;s/pattern//2;t begin'
```

or without the sed goto:

```
sed -e 's/\(pattern\)/\1\n/;h;s/.*\n//;s/pattern//g;H;g;s/\n.*\n//'
```

The generic solutions to remove from the nth (3 for example) position are:

```
sed -e ':begin;s/pattern//4;t begin'
sed -e 's/\(pattern\)/\1\n/;h;s/.*\n//3;s/pattern//g;H;g;s/\n.*\n//'
```

Answer (score 2):

A slight variation on @jillagre's answer *(modified for robustness)* could look like:

```
sed 's/p\(attern\)/p\n\1/;s///g;s/\n//'
```

...but in some `sed`s you may need to replace the `n` in the right-hand side of the first `s///`ubstitution statement with a literal `\n`ewline character.